# Can not play a mp4 video in android VIdeoview from a remote url

Tags: android, video, android-videoview, dailymotion-api

I have been trying to play a mp4 video from a remote url/dailymotion .I have played an other video in .3gp format from an other website ,it worked fine ,can not play any video from daily motion in my android app ,  here is my all code ,can not understand the issue.any help

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"

android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/VideoView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
   android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
```

`

public class songs  extends Activity {

```
String VideoURL = "http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x2trnoh_indian-girl-mehndi-dance_fun";


VideoView videoview;


@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Get the layout from video_main.xml

    setContentView(R.layout.songs);

    // Find your VideoView in your video_main.xml layout
    videoview = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VideoView);

    try {
        // Start the MediaController
        MediaController mediacontroller = new MediaController(
                songs.this);
        mediacontroller.setAnchorView(videoview);
        // Get the URL from String VideoURL
        Uri video = Uri.parse(VideoURL);
        videoview.setMediaController(mediacontroller);
        videoview.setVideoURI(video);


        videoview.requestFocus(); 
        videoview.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {

                videoview.start();
            }
        });

    } catch (Exception e) {

        System.out.println("Video Play Error :" + e.getMessage());
    }

   }}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASAIK, we can't play the dailymotion video's in normal android video view. So instead of video view  Why cant you try thier SDK [here](https://github.com/dailymotion/dailymotion-sdk-android) and render it in a webview.

Dailymotion provides a WebView based SDK that includes all the tricks required for you to play the video easily :

Github link:: [dailymotion-sdk-android/](https://github.com/dailymotion/dailymotion-sdk-android)

The README provides an easy example of integration

Hope it helps

Comment: i have downloaded this dailymotion-sdk-android ,how can i import this daily motion sdk in my eclipse project ,actually i am a complete beginner

Comment: follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23984962/how-to-play-dailymotion-video-inside-a-webview-in-android

Comment: thanks , really appreciate this , it worked ,thanks again

Comment: welcome. accept my answer if it helps to you.. that will be the real thanks :)